# make two different domains accessible to each other whm reseller account

Tags: permissions, share, domains, open-basedir

I have a WHM reseller account which has 2 configured domains (each one with his own cPanel account.

I need to be able share some code between both domains.

What should I do? 
One thing I need do do is to change open_basedir directive. But what about permissions?

My server has Apache installed with suPHP,

Comment: Does that code can be shared with all accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't tried but you could look at these:

- http://ask.metafilter.com/200070/And-way-to-include-in-PHP-across-publichtmls
- http://www.vpshostingforum.com/share-folder-between-different-cpanel-accounts-t8225.html